# How can I set a background image to vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently using Vs Code. But I don't know much about the IDE. I want to set a background image to IDE. Is it possible?
I've been searching for weeks. 
I installed an extension named `background` from `shalldie`. I have changed the json code with this:

```json
{
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active",
  "background.enabled": true,
  "background.loop": false,
  "background.useDefault": false,
  "background.useFront": false,
  "background.style": {
        "content": "''",
        "pointer-events": "none",
        "position": "absolute",
        "z-index": "99999",
        "width": "70%",
        "height": "100%",
        "margin-left":"30%",
        "background-position": "right",
        "background-size": "cover",
        "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
        "opacity": 0.1
    },
  "background.customImages": [
        "file//C:/madara.jpg",
    ]
}
```

after this, vs code wanted me to reload the IDE and I did. but nothing have changed.
After all this, I got another notification that says "Bracket Pair Colorizer is no longer being maintained.". But I don't know what does it mean.
I am using windows 10.
what do I need to do now?

Comment: You probably have a missing colon after `file` in your file URI. Can you check with `file://C:/madara.jpg`

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be a typo. `file//` vs `file://`

Comment: thank you guys. yeah, it was a typo and i just saw it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file:///C:/madara.jpg`

your path should add a '/' before drive letter